# Javascript / Jquery check if id already exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, exists

How can I check if an html tag with its unique id exists twice or more times ?

my pseudocode:

```
if($('#myId') > 1) {
  // exists twice
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ID selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) only catches the first element which is first in the page. So the length of [ID selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) should be `0` or `1` always.

So use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) instead and check it's length.

```
if($('[id="myId"]').length > 1) {
  // exists twice
}
```

```js
if ($('[id="myId"]').length > 1) {
  console.log('twice');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myId"></div>
<div id="myId"></div>
```

Comment: @JohnDoe2 : glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

### JQuery

```
if($("[id=someId]").length > 1) {
    //Do Something
}
```

or

```
if($("[id=someId]").size() > 1) {
    //Do Something
}
```

### Javascript

```
if(document.querySelectorAll("[id=someId]").length > 1) {
    //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too simple you might get from small search

```
if($("#" + name).length > 1) {
  // if exists twice 
}
```

how many time it `exists  = $("#" + name).length`

Comment: in valid condition.

Comment: in valid condition --  mean if condition match

Comment: As per asked question contion not matched as per asker need.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("[id='myId']").length > 1) {
    // write your code here
}
```